# php-mysql instead of delete row from mysql, get deleted value in one column

Tags: mysql

mysql table `2_1_paidused`

```
RowIdPaidusedUnique | TypeOfBookkeepingRecord
-------------------------------------------
     5              |      4
```

Then query

```
 DELETE FROM 2_1_paidused WHERE RowIdPaidusedUnique IN (?) AND TypeOfBookkeepingRecord = ?;
```

array

```
Array
(
[0] => 5
[1] => 4
)
```

But instead of deleted row i get existing row with empty column `TypeOfBookkeepingRecord`

Then I manually wrote 4 in column `TypeOfBookkeepingRecord` and repeated query. Row deleted.

`TypeOfBookkeepingRecord` structure `char(255)  utf8_general_ci`

Previously I had query `DELETE FROM 2_1_paidused WHERE RowIdPaidusedUnique IN (?);`. In such case row from mysql was deleted.

Any ideas how to delete row?

Answer (score 1):

TypeOfBookkeepingRecord is char and not number.
Try this:

```
Array
(
[0] => 5
[1] => "4"
)
```